# difference between community Licence and Force licence

Tags: community, force

I have a special question this time. in our organization, there is some data (visualforce Charts with buttons to change some fields), and we want to make this data not just visible to a group of people but make it possible for them to change these data if they want (they will just click on some buttons controlled by apex methods to change some fields in the records).

is it possible for them to do that with a community licence or they must get at least a force licence ?

Can you please highlight the main differences between the two licences and the limits of each one of them because there is no sufficient documentations for this subjects

thank you.

Comment: What objects are the visualforce charts on? Are the objects shared with your community users? There are MANY different community licenses available, far too many to give you a simple comparison.

Comment: Both , some standard and custom objets and honestly i do not know if the objects are shared or not

Answer (score 3):

Community Users are derived from your contacts and Community license has access to only to certain objects and will not have access to the Opportunity , Leads and Campaigns

Similarly partner license has access to only certain CRM Objects (Opportunity,Leads) .

The answer really depends on from which objects your charts are getting data from .

The Comparison Sheet for Community license are as below

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Pay attention to the column to figure which objects you need access .

Also try to find out  what other functionalities your user need and cross check to see if community license meets your needs .